# How to make class not derivable at all. is there any way?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Hi any one let me know How to make class not derivable at all. is there any way?
please let me know.
regards
Hara

Comment: A similar question on SO was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000908/is-it-possible-to-forbid-deriving-from-a-class-at-compile-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation) explanation on how do to it, and why it might not be a good idea, by Bjarne Stroustrup (creator of C++ himself).

Answer (score 4):

If your class has a private constructor, there is no way for a derived class to be instantiated.

See ["How can I set up my class so it won't be inherited from?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.11) on the C++ FAQ Lite.

Answer (score 3):

Make the ctor(s) private.

```
class not_derivable { private: not_derivable(){} };

class derived : public not_derivable {};

int main() { derived d; // diagnostic }
```

or the dtor:

```
class not_derivable { private: ~not_derivable(){} };

class derived : public not_derivable {};

int main() { not_derivable *nd = new not_derivable; derived d; //diagnostic }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the constructor private.

Comment: Just making constructor private is not enough. refer Link provided by "Charles Salvia". Thanks to both of you. :)